# Firefox. Memory/Offline cache device

Tags: firefox, offline, offline-caching, offlineapps, offline-mode

I develop a smartgwt app. It should work in an offline mode. But I have a problem. There is an app.nocache.js file, that doesn't want to be fetched from the Offline cache device of Firefox (see "about:cache" in Firefox). It is placed in the browser into both the Memory cache device and into the Offline cache device. It can only be fetched from the Memory cache device. If I switch into "Work Offline" this file cannot be read and I only see a gray screen. All files of my "offline.manifest" can be fetched from Offline cache device besides app.nocache.js. Why some files are put into Memory cache device? How can I prevent this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to smartgwt but to gwt . There are some posts on the web  you can find on the topic, one is [there](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/oS7ZKbxDtJI).
Hoping it could help you